# Not able to send json string as param in post request in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, ipad

I am trying to send the Json string as param in post request but i am not able to do that. I have an array of phone numbers from that i am generating a json string follwing is the code for that

```
int i=0;
NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (i=0; i<[all_contacts count]; i++)
{
    [contacts addObject:@{@"phone" : [all_contacts objectAtIndex:i]}];
}


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contacts options:0 error:&error];
if (!jsonData)
{
    //error here
}
else
{
     JsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"json string is %@",JsonString);
}
```

Now i am converting into nsdata to send to server using post request but i am not able to do that.

```
//append base url with main url
    NSString* urlString=[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:ADD_CONTACTS];

    // the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
    NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:api_key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property

    NSDictionary *_params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          JsonString, @"contacts",
                          nil];
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_params options:0 error:nil];

    request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"ns local data is%@", string);


    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Well, your `JsonString` might not be initialized, if the first jsonData is nil.

Comment: Json string is generated it is not nill.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to overthink it a bit. You have an array of dictionaries in `contacts`. Why not simply do the following?

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *_params = @{@"contacts": contacts};
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_params options:0 error:&error];
request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
```